# C# Regex.Match exclude brackets

Tags: regex

I have to extract all the text inside the curly brackets and at.

*This is my template @{test.html} bla bla bla @{test.html}*

I need **test.html** and **va**
This is the pattern I used.

```
\@{[A-Za-z\.]*}
```

Works fine but it return also the curly brackets.
**@{test.html}, @{test.html}**

how to exlude them.

Comment: This depends on the regex implementation I think. c#, js, ruby, ect are slightly diff. You can create a match group and then get values for that group. Though different implementations do it differently as far as I know

Comment: Hi, I'm using C#. I thought about extract value from subgroup but I was thinking to do in one shot (if is possible)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group you can look at this, should do what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use groups

```
@{([A-Za-z\.]*)}
```

http://regex101.com/r/oM0dW6/4

if you don't want to do this

```
(?<=@{)[A-Za-z\.]*(?=})
```

http://regex101.com/r/oM0dW6/5

Greetings

PS: Make sure that you really have everything needed to match any given text inside your text-group.